# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Issue while deployment

Tags: angular, http, cors

am newbie to angular 2, Am trying to fetch a list from my server using http GET request...

Browser thrown this error
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/student/list. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
student.service.ts:48 0 -  {"isTrusted":true}

I googled and added allow-control-allow-origin 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi
Now everything works fine..

Without that I have added the following line in serve.js but no use
headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*' },

But how to make this work without above shortcut..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: this is not a shortcut, this is how you should do it.

Comment: But i cannot say my customers to add the plugin in chrome right??? Am talking about after deployment

Comment: oh right, you have to add the header in your server, I didn't see the part about the chrome plugin, this has to be handled on server-side, it's not an angular issue..

Answer (score 2):

The CORS is a security feature of browsers, it's not bug to get around, but something you should comply with.

When deploying, you can either serve both your Angular SPA and your backend from the same origin (eg. using some reverse proxy) or you must configure the CORS headers for your backend.